Error when using GitHub composite actions with matrix
I have my ci_test.yml at repo_name/.github/workflows :
jobs:
  Clients:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [1.23.x]
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    env:
      GOPATH: ${{ github.workspace }}
      GOBIN: ${{ github.workspace }}/bin
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.REPO_PAT_SERVICE_IT }}
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.GOPATH }}/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          path: ${{ env.GOPATH }}/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
      - id: common_workflow
        uses: ./.github/actions/
        with:
          go_version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
          os: ${{ matrix.os }}
          github_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_PAT_SERVICE_IT }}


I have my composite action action.yml at repo_name/.github/actions :
name: "common workflow"
inputs:
  go_version:
    required: true
    type: string
  os:
    required: true
    type: string
  github_token:
    required: true
    type: string

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Install Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: ${{ inputs.go_version }}

    - name: Configure git
      uses: repo_name/.github-private/git-configure@v1
      with:
        username: repo-service-it
        token: ${{ inputs.github_token }}


Mine is a private repository. After pushing this, I get the error
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/repo_name/repo_name/.github/actions'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?

Any idea how to resolve this?

You set path on checkout, so your action really is at ${{ env.GOPATH }}/src/github.com/${{ github.repository }}/.github/actions and not ./.github/actions

Go doesn't require this directory structure any longer (more or less since modules were adopted), you can likely drop that path everywhere.

The issue was with my path. Thanks @BenjaminW.
